# How to convert MultiSelect values from Active Choice Parameter in Jenkins into an array or list?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have parameterized job with 'list' MultiSelect parameter in Jenkins:
[image]

I want to build this job only with selected values:
[image]

And for this purpose, I want to pass this selected values to pipeline script in this job and convert them into an array or list.

The following code doesn't work properly:
[image]

Please, help me to write the proper code in groovy to convert selected values to array or list.

Thanks,
Anastasiia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming parameter name "list" and property setting described in question, below pipeline code worked for me.

String[] arr= "${params.list}".split(','); 
for (x in arr) { 
    echo "$x \n"
}

This will print each selected values on new line.